# Oracle: How to get the result from the table with column containing range of string

Tags: oracle

I have the table with a `varchar2` column containing values like     `(1,2,20-25,222-256)`

Now I have to filter the records based on the following search criteria `(24,210,300,250)`

Sample Records

```
Id | RangeOfString
---------------------------
1  | 20-25, 101, 222-256, 1001-1045, 1046, 1047, 1048
2  | 1, 2, 3, 2100-2300
3  | 56-89, 186-326, 548, 601, 875
```

Expected Result

```
Id | RangeOfString
---------------------------
1  | 20-25, 101, 222-256, 1001-1045, 1046, 1047, 1048
3  | 56-89, 186-326, 548, 601, 875
```

Comment: Why don't you normalize your data? Then your query would extremely easy

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, thanks for your quick reply, i have read only access to the table.

Comment: It's awful, you would need to split the comma separated values into rows, and then 2 paths, individual value convert to number and compare, or, a range split into low/high values, convert and compare using between. Hideous. (oh and hope like heck no errors occur on conversion to numbers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a function to return a collection:

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TYPE intlist IS TABLE OF INTEGER;
/

CREATE PROCEDURE splitGroupedList(
  p_grouped   IN VARCHAR2,
  p_delimiter IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT ',',
  p_separator IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT '-'
) RETURN intlist DETERMINISTIC
AS
  v_start   PLS_INTEGER := 1;
  v_end     PLS_INTEGER;
  v_sep     PLS_INTEGER;
  v_range   VARCHAR2(4000);
  v_lower   INTEGER;
  v_upper   INTEGER;
  v_numbers intlist := intlist();
  c_del_len CONSTANT PLS_INTEGER := LENGTH( p_delimiter );
  c_sep_len CONSTANT PLS_INTEGER := LENGTH( p_separator );
BEGIN
  IF p_grouped IS NULL THEN
    RETURN v_numbers;
  END IF;
  LOOP
    EXIT WHEN v_start := 0;
    v_end := INSTR( p_grouped, p_delimiter, v_start );
    IF v_end = 0 THEN
      v_range := SUBSTR( p_grouped, v_start );
      v_start := 0;
    ELSE
      v_range := SUBSTR( p_grouped, v_start, v_end - v_start );
      v_start := v_end + c_del_len;
    END IF;
    IF v_range IS NULL THEN
      CONTINUE;
    END IF;
    v_sep := INSTR( v_range, p_separator );
    IF v_sep = 0 THEN
      v_lower := TO_NUMBER( v_range );
      v_upper := v_lower;
    ELSE
      v_lower := TO_NUMBER( SUBSTR( v_range, 1, v_sep - 1 ) );
      v_upper := TO_NUMBER( SUBSTR( v_range, v_sep + c_sep_len ) );
    END IF;
    FOR i IN v_lower .. v_upper LOOP
      v_numbers.EXTEND;
      v_numbers( v_numbers.COUNT ) := i;
    END LOOP;
  END LOOP;
  RETURN v_numbers;
END;
/
```

**Query**:

```
WITH your_data ( Id, RangeOfString ) AS (
  SELECT 1, '20-25,101,222-256,1001-1045,1046,1047,1048' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, '1,2,3,2100-2300' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, '56-89,186-326,548,601,875' FROM DUAL
)
SELECT *
FROM   your_data
WHERE  intlist( 24,210,300,250 ) MULTISET INTERSECT splitGroupedList( RangeOfString ) IS NOT EMPTY;
```

**Output**:

```
ID RANGEOFSTRING
-- ------------------------------------------
 1 20-25,101,222-256,1001-1045,1046,1047,1048
 3 56-89,186-326,548,601,875
```

Comment: you made my day :) Solution works like a charm. Thanks for your time and effort.